# Expression Engine: Use Category URL Titles In Links - YES / Category URL Indicator

Tags: php, expressionengine

I have just started using "Use Category URL Titles In Links" in Expression Engine and defined my "Category URL Indicator" how do I specify which template a category page uses though or does it have to go to the index page?

Comment: By 'this' do you mean expressionengine?

Comment: Edited Question - By "this" I meant "Use Category URL Titles In Links" in Expression Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer off the Expression Engine forum:

> EE’s category URLs are /templategroup/template/category/category_url_title/ - for a multi-entry page that displays all the entries in that category.  Once you click an entry to go to a “single-view” template the category is no longer in the URL (but you can display it on the page).